# Looking for the title of a book with a boy and an alien creature

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult

I've been trying to find out about a book I read when I was in my early teens. This would have been late 90's to very early 2000s. All I can remember is that a boy finds an alien creature that looks jellyfish-like and over the course of the book it changes and becomes something more predatory.

It 'swims' in the air I think but what I remember most clearly is the chapter titles had illustrations of the change in stages so if you flipped through it you could see the creature change (I think it basically turns inside out as it transforms).